# How do I redirect subdomains that do not exist?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am trying to redirect using .htaccess in the following fashion. I am not all that familiar with .htaccess, so I'm not sure it can be done. Also, I don't know if how I am intending to do it follows best practices for SEO.

```
www.domain.com                > domain.com 301

ks.domain.com                 > kansas.domain.com 301

ia.domain.com                 > iowa.domain.com 301

domain.com/sites              > domain.com 301

domain.com/sites/iowa         > iowa.domain.com 301

nonexistent.domain.com        > domain.com 302

domain.com/sites/nonexistent  > domain.com 302
```

My biggest question is if I can detect a nonexistent subdomain and redirect. I would love to see how all of the above is accomplished.

Comment: @Johnsonmk2 What is unclear about the accepted answer?

Comment: I suppose by "do not exist" you actually mean that the sub-domains exist but there are no corresponding websites for them, correct?

Comment: Yes Alexis. What is meant is if I forward all `*.domain.com` to `domain.com/*`, detect if that folder (website) does not exist, then redirect to `domain.com`. The accepted answer was quite detailed about how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to add wildcard subdomains by creating a subdomain with an `*` as its name, only if your web host allows you to do so. And this must be in your `.htaccess`, try to test it to see if it works:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ks\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://kansas.domain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ia\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://iowa.domain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) / [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/iowa/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://iowa.domain.com/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/ [R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/ [R=302]
```

Just use `-f` to test if a requested file exists and is a regular file, `-s` if it exists and has a file size greater than 0 and `-d` to test if it exists and is a directory.

Comment: I appreciate you help. It did get me a long way on setting up my .htaccess. I would up-vote you answer if I could. Maybe someday.

Comment: Yes. I ended up doing it a bit differently because my structure changed, but you information helped me understand what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific subdomains that do not exist, well you'll just have to create them, and then redirect.

To catch all erroneous subdomains, say I accidentally type `metaa.stackoverlow.com`, use a wildcard: `*.stackoverflow.com`. In cpanel, this just involves ticking a checkbox that asks 'make wildcard?' or similar. To edit .htaccess directly, just enter `*` in place of each specific subdomain.

Note that this also applies for any directories:

`subdomain.site.com/*`

`*.site.com/dir`

`*.site.com/*`