# How to make website to redirect to a page when subdomain not founds

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

There is an issue in my website that when I try a domain like: abc.domain.com when subdomain abc is registered, everything works fine. But when I type xyz.domain.com when subdomain xyz is not registered the browser shows page not found but I want to redirect it to a custom error file for subdomain not found.

Comment: Check out this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802257/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-that-do-not-exist

Comment: You need to clarify where the problem is e.g.: Do you have wildcard dns - does the request for `xyz.domain.com` reach your server?

Comment: I have wildcard server but the request of unregistered domain does not reach to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a default vhost (in apache, it is the *first* one) and have all of your other vhosts (the ones with registered hostnames) come after the default. Then in the default vhost, add:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdomain-not-found-error.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

So any request for a subdomain that exists, will get handled by that vhost, but a request for one that doesn't exist will get sent to the default vhost, which will always return a `/subdomain-not-found-error.php`
 file with a 404 error.